# Compile libpcap using Android NDK

Tags: android, linux, compilation, android-ndk, libpcap

I've been doing a lot of attempts to get `libpcap` compiled for Android, and I don't see any pattern or any progress worth writing down.

I have a very simple sniffer (that works fine in a MIPS linux) that uses libpcap, so I thought to myself *oh, ok... no biggie... I'll just compile libpcap for Android (in the end, Android is just a Linux)...* and here's where the problems started. I have no idea on how to compile libpcap using `ndk-build` and the `Android.mk` and all that infrastructure.

I have the Android NDK in a directory. That NDK has the toolchains built (I have a lot of directories under `~/Documents/Projects/Android_NDK/toolchains/` ) but none of the toolchains has `libpcap` available.

I've tried with two different libpcap version or... branches:

The Android one, which is the one I'd like to use,
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libpcap/

and the regular one: 
http://www.tcpdump.org/release/libpcap-1.5.3.tar.gz

All tries I've done have been very unsuccessful. I've seen the question [Android NDK: Link using a pre-compiled static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463518/android-ndk-link-using-a-pre-compiled-static-library) which is similar, but I'm still getting various errors.

I have downloaded those pcap libraries to their own directories. Maybe is that the problem? Do I need to put the Android libpcap in some directory within the NDK root directory and re-create the toolchains?

I'm using NDK-r9 on a MacOSX 10.9.2 64bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally!!

After getting annoyed by the non existing headers in  and stuff like that, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952878/android-ndk-trying-to-port-jnetpcap), that pointed to a SVN repo (http://sourceforge.net/p/prueba-android/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/jni/) with a libpcap that compiled!

If someone else wants additional details on how my Android.mk and directory structure looks like, please add a comment and I'll extend this answer.

Comment: That's quite old version, isn't it?

Comment: Yeep... But if it compiles, it ships! **:-D**

Comment: Do you find how Android.mk and directory structure looks?

Answer (score 1):

Please read an excellent article at http://blog.umitproject.org/2011/05/libpcap-for-android.html. There are instructions that will help you link to libpcap, but the most important takeaway is that *you cannot use libpcap on non-rooted Android*. So maybe it's not worth your effort.

On a rooted device, you can simply install a free sniffer like [Shark for Root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.shark).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had already tried it **;-)** 
I keep getting an error: 
Android_NDKs/external/libpcap/pcap-linux.c:218:30: fatal error: linux/net_tstamp.h: No such file or directory

Also, thanks for the hint about the rooted device. I forgot to specify that in the question, actually. I do have one with su installed and giving my apps root access **:-)**

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is having problems compiling libpcap for Android using the NDK, there is version 1.5.2 here with a built Android.mk file in it: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libpcap.git and instructions for compiling this using the NDK are here: http://ducbh.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/cross-compile-libpcap-for-android.html . I can confirm this works using the current NDK (r10b)...although you may have to add AndroidManifest.xml (blank) and and Application.mk that points to your Android.mk file.

I don't think it would be that difficult to modify the .mk file for the current libpcap version (1.6.2)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone ends up here in 2022+. You can now cross-compile for Android from the [official source](https://www.tcpdump.org). Steps:

**First, setup the NDK**:
Download [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/) (I used [r21e](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r21e-linux-x86_64.zip)) and extract to a directory of your choosing:

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir Android
$ unzip android-ndk-r21e-linux-x86_64.zip
```

Prepare the environment variables for cross-compilation by placing the commands below (replace `<YOUR_USER>`) into a file named `setup_env.sh` (can be saved anywhere):

```
export NDK=/home/<YOUR_USER>/Android/android-ndk-r21e
export TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
export TARGET=aarch64-linux-android
export API=21
export AR=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET-ar
export AS=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET-as
export CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET$API-clang
export CXX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET$API-clang++
export LD=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET-ld
export RANLIB=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET-ranlib
export STRIP=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET-strip
```

**Now, build libpcap**:

1. Download libpcap tar ball (e.g. https://www.tcpdump.org/release/libpcap-1.10.1.tar.gz)
2. Extract (in a directory of your choosing): `tar xf libpcap-1.10.1.tar.gz`
3. Prepare your env: `source <path_to>/setup_env.sh`
4. Change into the extract libpcap directory and configure: `./configure --host=aarch64-linux-android`
5. I found the Makefile generated had the wrong linker set (line 48), so I had to change it to: `LD = /home/<YOUR_USER>/Android/android-ndk-r21e/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld`
6. Finally, build: `make`

This build worked for me with running [tcpreplay](http://tcpreplay.appneta.com) on a rooted Android, hopefully it works for other purposes as well!