# Compile jpcap library with Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, jpcap

I want to use jpcap library in one android project, but I can't compile the native code of libpcap library. Are there any compiled with Android NDK jni folder and Android.mk file for jpcap library ??

Comment: You've seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646344/compile-libpcap-using-android-ndk

Comment: I have already seen this issue. However, using the JnetPcap library, I have an other problem. When I was executing the findAllDevs () function, this returns null list.